# Sencha Touch SQL Proxy not show Load More button

Tags: list, proxy, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, store

I create an WebSQL database on my Sencha Touch project. An table named Product have 100 record.

I config my Store as
Ext

```
.define('Mark.store.Product', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'Mark.model.Product',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Sql'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        model: 'Mark.model.Product',
        storeId: 'Product',
        proxy: {
            type: 'sql',
            database: 'osadb'
        }
    }
});
```

By default it will load 25 record from the Product table to the product List on View (listpaging plugin added)

And this is my list configuration:
 {

```
                                xtype: 'list',
                                docked: 'bottom',
                                height: '100%',
                                hidden: false,
                                itemId: 'productList',
                                emptyText: 'Data not found',
                                itemTpl: [
                                    '<div style="font-size:15px">{METRO_DESC}</div>',
                                    '<div style="font-size:13px" class="mark-list-item-secondary">{Brand} {PACKSIZE}</div>'
                                ],
                                scrollToTopOnRefresh: false,
                                store: 'Product',
                                useSimpleItems: false,
                                plugins: [
                                    {
                                        autoPaging: true,
                                        type: 'listpaging'
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
```

When i run the project. It have load 25 record to screen, and it show "No more records" at the bottom
.
But the table Product in Database have 100 record. The Store just load 25, why it's not show the "Load More" button instead of "No more record"

Comment: Hi,I cannot see where you limit the store to 25 items. Seems you filtered the store. you need to tell the store to load 25. Then anther 25 via plugin. Isn't it?

Comment: The Sencha WebSql proxy does not set the store totalCount property. The list paging plugin needs to know the totalCount of records in the data source. One solution is to extend the Sencha Touch WebSql proxy class read operaton. Get the total count of records from the database and set the store totalCount property in the read operation.